# Extension-less URLs on IIS6 with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I remember attempting to use an extension-less URL format in a CMS I wrote way back when .NET 2.0 first came out.  The problem was deploying to an IIS6 server.  It made it practically impossible.  I had to programmatically create folders for the path (tons of folders) and insert a dummy "Default.aspx" in there to get the request routed to ASP.NET.  Of course, I hated that "solution" and had to abandon using extension-less URLs.

Now that I am getting started with ASP.NET MVC, I again want (need) to use extension-less URLs. Can somebody tell me if I am going to have the same headaches when I try to deploy my app to IIS6?  Is anything special required to get this type of URL structure to work in IIS6?

Answer (score 3):

Extension-less URLs are possible with IIS 6, but it requires setting up a "wildcard" ISAPI mapping in the site's Application Config.  This has the downside of causing *all* requests to get processed by the ASP.NET ISAPI filter including static files like images, javascript, etc.

Here is an [excellent blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) from Phil Haack about the different options for setting up ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6.  The wildcard instructions are about halfway down.

Comment: Yeah there are *definitely* performance implications with passing all requests to `aspnet_isapi.dll`.  Crap.  If Windows Server 2008 was not so damn expensive, I would upgrade!

Comment: Looking at the comments, it appears like there are other issues that spring up as well.  And most of them Dr. Phil does not even respond to!

Answer (score 1):

Note that wildcard ISAPI mappings are no longer required as of .NET 4.0:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/how-asp-net-mvc-routing-works-and-its-impact-on-the-performance-of-static-requests)